# Session does not match image PHP

Tags: php, session

I am wondering why the characters in the image that is generated by this script does dont match the characters set for the session. I can't find why this is, if someone could help, that would be great. Thanks, Lea.

```
// Font directory + font name
$font = 'wordpress/wp-content/themes/boldy/fonts/SF Juggernaut Bold.ttf';
// Total number of lines
$lineCount = 20;
// Size of the font
$fontSize = 19;
// Height of the image
$height = 38;
// Width of the image
$width = 120;
$img_handle = imagecreate ($width, $height) or die ("Cannot Create image");
// Set the Background Color RGB
$backColor = imagecolorallocate($img_handle, 242, 242, 242);
// Set the Line Color RGB
$lineColor = imagecolorallocate($img_handle, 207, 207, 207);
// Set the Text Color RGB
$txtColor = imagecolorallocate($img_handle, 95, 95, 95);

// Generate
$string = "bcdefghijklmopqrstwxyz023456789";
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
    $pos = rand(0,36);
    $str .= $string{$pos};
}

$textbox = imagettfbbox($fontSize, 0, $font, $str) or die('Error in imagettfbbox function');

$x = ($width - $textbox[4])/2;
$y = ($height - $textbox[5])/2;

imagettftext($img_handle, $fontSize, 0, $x, $y, $txtColor, $font , $str) or die('Error in imagettftext function');

for($i=0;$i<$lineCount;$i++){
    $x1 = rand(0,$width);$x2 = rand(0,$width);
    $y1 = rand(0,$width);$y2 = rand(0,$width);
    imageline($img_handle,$x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$lineColor);
}

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($img_handle,NULL,100);
imagedestroy($img_handle);

session_start();
$_SESSION['img_number'] = $str;
```

**UPDATE:** Upon testing I have noted that the first time the image is loaded, the session DOES NOT get set, so that when the image is refreshed, the session is set with the last $str value

Comment: Try putting your session start / session variable set code before your `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`

Comment: @onteria_ - this doesnt seem to make a difference. The session string seems out of sync with the image characters.

Answer (score 1):

You may have problems calling session_start() if your headers are already sent.

Change

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($img_handle,NULL,100);
imagedestroy($img_handle);

session_start();
$_SESSION['img_number'] = $str;
```

To

```
session_start();
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($img_handle,NULL,100);
imagedestroy($img_handle);

$_SESSION['img_number'] = $str;
```

Comment: No it's there: `$str .= $string{$pos};`

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't looking for a line like that... forgot PHP allowed for such declarations.

Answer (score 0):

If you debug your script with something like firebug or devtools, then it calls your image twice.

Try to disable your firebug/devtools and you will see the PROFIT.

Comment: I wish this were true for me, but I disabled firebug already and its still the same.

Comment: Also try to add some loggin to understand how many times and from where your captcha script called.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();

// Font directory + font name
$font = 'wordpress/wp-content/themes/boldy/fonts/SF Juggernaut Bold.ttf';
// Total number of lines
$lineCount = 20;
// Size of the font
$fontSize = 19;
// Height of the image
$height = 38;
// Width of the image
$width = 120;
$img_handle = imagecreate ($width, $height) or die ("Cannot Create image");
// Set the Background Color RGB
$backColor = imagecolorallocate($img_handle, 242, 242, 242);
// Set the Line Color RGB
$lineColor = imagecolorallocate($img_handle, 207, 207, 207);
// Set the Text Color RGB
$txtColor = imagecolorallocate($img_handle, 95, 95, 95);

// Generate
$string = "bcdefghijklmopqrstwxyz023456789";
$str = '';
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
    $pos = rand(0,36);
    $str .= substr($string, $pos, 1);
}

$_SESSION['img_number'] = $str;

$textbox = imagettfbbox($fontSize, 0, $font, $str) or die('Error in imagettfbbox function');

$x = ($width - $textbox[4])/2;
$y = ($height - $textbox[5])/2;

imagettftext($img_handle, $fontSize, 0, $x, $y, $txtColor, $font , $str) or die('Error in imagettftext function');

for($i=0;$i<$lineCount;$i++){
    $x1 = rand(0,$width);$x2 = rand(0,$width);
    $y1 = rand(0,$width);$y2 = rand(0,$width);
    imageline($img_handle,$x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$lineColor);
}

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($img_handle,NULL,100);
imagedestroy($img_handle);
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to make any difference. Thanks

Comment: Lea, do you get any font output at all?